# Python. Error when trying to create a new directory using the filename if it has a special character in it

Tags: python, directory

My script searches the directory that it's in and will create new directories using the file names that it has found and moves them to that directory: John-doe-taxes.hrb -> John-doe/John-does-taxes.hrb. It works fine until it runs into an umlaut character then it will create the directory and return an "Error 2" saying that it cannot find the file. I'm fairly new to programming and the answers i've found have been to add a

`coding: utf-8`

line to the file which doesn't work I believe because i'm not using umlauts in my code i'm dealing with umlaut files. One thing I was curious about, does this problem just occur with umlauts or other special characters as well? This is the code i'm using, I appreciate any advice provided.

```
import os
import re
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join


dir = dirname(abspath(__file__))
(root, dirs, files) = os.walk(dir).next() 
p = re.compile('(.*)-taxes-') 
count = 0
for file in files:
    match = p.search(file)
    if match:
        count = count + 1
        print("Files processed: " + str(count))
        dir_name = match.group(1) 
        full_dir = join(dir, dir_name)
        if not os.access(full_dir, os.F_OK):
            os.mkdir(full_dir)
        os.rename(join(dir, file), join(full_dir, file)) 
raw_input()
```

Comment: what operating system are you running on?

Comment: What filename does this fail on and what error do you get?

Comment: The name of the file is Gülhan-taxes.hrb. The error that I get is
 
`Files processed: 1 Traceback (most recent call last>: File "<directorypath>\batchmove.py", line 23, 
in <module> os.rename(join(dir, file), join(full_dir, file))` 
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is passing `str`s to `os.rename` that aren't in the system encoding.  As long as the filenames only use ascii characters this will work, however outside that range you're likely to run into problems.

The best solution is probably to work in unicode.  The filesystem functions should return unicode strings if you give them unicode arguments.  `open` should work fine on windows with unicode filenames.

If you do:

`dir = dirname(abspath(unicode(__file__)))`

Then you should be working with unicode strings the whole way.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks a lot, i'll never forget that bit of code the rest of my programming life.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider would be to use Python 3. It has native support for unicode as the default. I'm not sure if you would have to do anything to change anything in the above code for it to work, but there is a python script in the examples to transition Python2 code to Python3.

Sorry I can't help you with Python2, I had a similar problem and just transitioned my project to Python3--ended up just being a bit easier for me!